# Migration of Ec2 from AWS cloud to on premises Vmware datacenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, vmware

I have a QA environment in aws cloud (About 10 ec2 instance) and would like to move it back on to an on-premises datacenter (Vmware). What be the procedure for this entire migration? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth looking into vCenter Converter: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1018015

Or depending on how you deployed the QA environment, Amazon may have some tools available as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html